# Override or disable implicitly imported assemblies in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, msbuild

I'm migrating our .NET 4.x framework to .NET 7.0 and I'm hitting a snag I have not been able to work around. I have created an extended version of the standard System.Configuration dll (publicly signed) that I want to keep around (why this extended version and why I want to keep it is not the issue).

In .NET 4.x, I referenced my dll and it just worked (the standard dll provided by Mono or Windows .NET framework was successfully overriden).

In .NET 7.0, I can reference my dll, but I get myriads of implicitely included assemblies in my projects, and one of them is the standard System.Configuration. I cannot remove it from my project because "it was evaluated from targets". When I compile, I get a CS1703 error ("Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported") and indeed the compiler command line contains both the standard dll and my dll.

Is there a way to override or remove or disable an implicitely imported assembly? I guess I could avoid referencing my assembly then use a PostBuildEvent to copy it anyway, but I'm trying to find a cleaner way.

I've tried removing the reference by hand in the csproj but no luck:

`<Reference Remove="System.Configuration"/>`

Answer (score 0):

In your project, set the `DisableImplicitFrameworkReferences` property to `true`.

See the [MSBuild reference for .NET SDK projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props) documentation for [`DisableImplicitFrameworkReferences`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#disableimplicitframeworkreferences).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. From what I gather, this setting totally disables implicit references. Most dependencies seem quite difficult to find, I have trouble finding something as standard as System.IO.Path by hand. It would be great if we had a way of giving a hint to msbuild as to where to search for a specific dependency... Maybe by hosting my own nuget feed?

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio on Windows? Before you disable the implicit framework references, check the properties on the item(s) under Dependencies\Frameworks in your project. That will show the path that is being used. I expect it is the `packs` directory within the `dotnet` install directory. e.g. 'c:\program files\dotnet\packs'

Comment: I'm an adventurer, I'm using Rider on Linux :) But I can see the paths in Rider too. I will search in this direction and I'll come back here whether I find what I'm searching for or not. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I work on both Windows and macOS - so a better example then is '/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs' :)